# Replacing sublists with criterion or Interpolation for a smooth curve

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting, interpolation, data

Supposing we have the following [list](https://gofile.io/?c=SbQFNU) (very small, can be copied into a notebook directly)

```
{
{1.25, 0},
{1.3, 0.125},
{1.4, 0.175},
{1.5, 0.225},
{1.6, 0.275}, {1.7, 0.275},
{1.8, 0.325},
{1.9, 0.375}, {2., 0.375}, {2.1, 0.375},
{2.2, 0.425}, {2.3, 0.425},
{2.4, 0.475}, {2.5, 0.475}, {2.6, 0.475}, {2.7, 0.475},
{2.8, 0.525}, {2.9, 0.525}, {3., 0.525},
{3.1, 0.575}, {3.2, 0.575}, {3.3, 0.575}, {3.4, 0.575}, {3.5, 0.575},
{3.6, 0.625}, {3.7, 0.625}, {3.8, 0.625}, {3.9, 0.625}, {4., 0.625},
{4.1, 0.675}, {4.2, 0.675}, {4.3, 0.675}, {4.4, 0.675}, {4.5, 0.675}, {4.6, 0.675}, {4.7, 0.675},
...}
```

What special in the list is that it has **some adjacent sublists with the same 2nd elements and continuous 1st element**, as highlighted by the line breaks. By plotting it, we can see the abovementioned feature causes the horizontally aligned points in a step-like fashion.

```
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}}, ImageSize -> 400, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
```

[image]

What I want is a smooth "fitting" curve instead of a discrete point-plot. To this end, I tried `Interpolation`, but it turns out that increasing `InterpolationOrder` is of no help. Btw, adding an option of `Method -> "Hermite"` or `Method -> "Spline"` is useless, either. I also tried `Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x]`, which turns out to be even worse.

```
interpdata = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 10];
Plot[interpdata[x], {x, data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
```

[image]

So I want to manipulate the original data by replacing the **adjacent sublists with the same 2nd element** using a procedure like this:

Checking the length of the adjacent sublists with the same 2nd element and using the mean value of their 1st elements as the 1st element of a new sublist, then replacing those sublists with the resulting sublist, i.e., `{mean of 1st elements, the same 2nd elem}`. For example,

`{1.6, 0.275}, {1.7, 0.275}` => `{1.65, 0.275}`,

`{1.9, 0.375}, {2., 0.375}, {2.1, 0.375}` => `{2, 0.375}`

`{2.4, 0.475}, {2.5, 0.475}, {2.6, 0.475}, {2.7, 0.475}` => `{2.55,0.475}`

**I guess this can be achieved with [SequenceSplit](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceSplit.html) and the new list should give me a reasonable curve. But I have difficulty to use `SequenceSplit` in this case.** Could anybody help me? It will be great if a certain *interpolating method* can be compared to the plot of the new list. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
v={{1.25, 0},{1.3, 0.125},{1.4, 0.175},{1.5, 0.225},{1.6, 0.275}, {1.7, 0.275},
  {1.8, 0.325},{1.9, 0.375}, {2., 0.375}, {2.1, 0.375},{2.2, 0.425}, {2.3, 0.425},
  {2.4, 0.475}, {2.5, 0.475}, {2.6, 0.475}, {2.7, 0.475},{2.8, 0.525}, {2.9, 0.525},
  {3., 0.525},{3.1, 0.575}, {3.2, 0.575}, {3.3, 0.575}, {3.4, 0.575}, {3.5, 0.575},
  {3.6, 0.625}, {3.7, 0.625}, {3.8, 0.625}, {3.9, 0.625}, {4., 0.625},{4.1, 0.675},
  {4.2, 0.675}, {4.3, 0.675}, {4.4, 0.675}, {4.5, 0.675}, {4.6, 0.675}, {4.7, 0.675}};
vs=Map[Mean,Split[v,Last[#1]==Last[#2]&]];
ListPlot[vs,Joined->True]
```